# Facebook flux deficiency

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

In the flux-chat example, the MessageSection listens to both the ThreadStore and MessageStore so it renders when ThreadStore store changes and once again when the MessageStore changes. However, since its state depends on both, the first render is done when the state is not complete.

Unless i'm missing something this is not good, no?

This is only one example but the pattern is repeating.

**Update:** After the long discussion thread here are the conclusions:

1. React makes sure that `render` only fires once at the end even if `setState` is called multiple times.
2. The getter functions to build the state will be called multiple times but since these are pure functions they will not cause bugs but only a 'small' overhead.

My suggestion is to use a maximum of one store per react component that gathers all the state from all the other stores by coordinating with them using `waitFor` and then notifies the component when the state is ready. This way there is no overhead and no reliance on React's internal magic. This is similar to having a 'View Model' but there is no 2 way binding and the data flows in one direction from the store to the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this is not a problem as long as each store is internally consistent. If there are data dependencies between stores, the stores can use `waitFor` to ensure data propagates in the correct order.

Furthermore, even though `setState` is called twice (once for each change event), the React synthetic event system batches multiple `setState` calls together into just one render, which happens *after* both actions are handled.

To prove this case, I made the following modifications to the project:

```diff
diff --git a/examples/flux-chat/js/components/MessageSection.react.js b/examples/flux-chat/js/components/MessageSection.react.js
index b803174..05bad0b 100644
--- a/examples/flux-chat/js/components/MessageSection.react.js
+++ b/examples/flux-chat/js/components/MessageSection.react.js
@@ -50,6 +50,7 @@ var MessageSection = React.createClass({
   },

   render: function() {
+    console.log("message section render");
     var messageListItems = this.state.messages.map(getMessageListItem);
     return (
       <div className="message-section">
diff --git a/examples/flux-chat/js/stores/MessageStore.js b/examples/flux-chat/js/stores/MessageStore.js
index 995ef39..3436a0f 100644
--- a/examples/flux-chat/js/stores/MessageStore.js
+++ b/examples/flux-chat/js/stores/MessageStore.js
@@ -94,6 +94,7 @@ var MessageStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
 });

 MessageStore.dispatchToken = ChatAppDispatcher.register(function(action) {
+  console.log("message store", action.type);

   switch(action.type) {

diff --git a/examples/flux-chat/js/stores/ThreadStore.js b/examples/flux-chat/js/stores/ThreadStore.js
index a73ceb3..e14f35d 100644
--- a/examples/flux-chat/js/stores/ThreadStore.js
+++ b/examples/flux-chat/js/stores/ThreadStore.js
@@ -103,6 +103,7 @@ var ThreadStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
 });

 ThreadStore.dispatchToken = ChatAppDispatcher.register(function(action) {
+  console.log("thread store", action.type);

   switch(action.type) {
```

In the JavaScript console, you can see that `MessageSection` is not re-rendering until both actions have been processed.

[image]

So, in this case, the only extra work is that `getStateFromStores` is being called twice instead of once, but I believe the tiny bit of extra overhead is worth it to take advantage of the simplified mental model of simply emitting a change event from any store that needs to update.

Remember that the golden rule of flux is: **the only way to mutate store data is via actions**. Functions exposed on the store should *never* mutate data—they should be pure functions. Thus, calling them more than once will not cause bugs.

Comment: It's not true that both finish updating before MessageSection receives a change event. I don't know why you say that.
Second, I'm not sure how the synthetic event system is batching and under which conditions. Is when the 2 setStat are close enough?
Third, I think the mental model is broken and rendering an incomplete state is not only inefficient but can cause subtle bugs.

Comment: @Delucia You're right - I was thinking of something very different. The change event emission is also synchronous.

Comment: @Delucia I've updated my answer with facts that are a bit more... factual (and include proof :)

Comment: You're right. The render method is only firing once. It's not obvious but probably it's the 'synthetic' stuff. However it's confusing because if you look at the MessageSection.getMessageListItem it's firing twice although it's inside the render function which fire once!
I don't agree that getStateFromStores being fired multiple times is ok not because of the overhead but everything is firing multiple times like the UnreadThreadStore.getCount and things done many times when they're intended to be run once can cause bugs.

Comment: @Delucia The code is `this.state.messages.map(getMessageListItem)`, which means `getMessageListItem` will be called once for each message in `this.state.messages`.

Comment: I see. I think that settles it. The render always fires once and the store functions being pure (like getCount) there is no place for bugs.. only overhead!:). Personally I think a less confusing model would be if each component had a maximum of one store that gathers all the state and emit's onChange only once when needed.

Comment: @Delucia That's a great point. In practice I think it's a good practice to wrap components in functions/components that watch the stores for you and pass data as props. Combined with `shouldComponentUpdate` you can get a pretty good flow going.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last remark clearly. Do you have a small example (a JSFiddle maybe?)

Comment: @Delucia No JSFiddle handy, but there's some discussion at this GitHub issue: https://github.com/BinaryMuse/fluxxor/issues/117 as well as a couple examples toward the bottom of the opening comment. In that example, the `RecipeList` component doesn't connect itself to the flux stores—it's given data by some wrapping function, which is responsible for connecting to the stores.

Comment: Ok. I think adding a other concepts like controllers and wrappers increases the complexity of the framework as opposed to my suggestion which uses existing concepts thus keeping the complexity at bay.